# independence of vectors

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, independence

I have the next proof:

I am proving that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent where $[X^T,Y^T]^T$ are Normal distributed in $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$

The first implication I think that is direct, i.e.

$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=0$ because $X$ and $Y$ are independent $(E(X)=E(Y))$

Now the other implication, I suppose that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ from this I have that 
$$\operatorname{ Var}((X,Y))=\Sigma=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \Sigma_{XX} & 0 \\  0 & \Sigma_{YY}  
 \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
Then, I consider $B=\mu+\Sigma^{1/2}Z$ where $(Z_1,Z_2)$ are independent standard normal Gaussian, I have that $B\sim{\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)}$.

Now I should proof that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are independent, How to conclude it, I think that are independent but I am not very clear.

Comment: For the first direction, do you mean that it's because $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$? $E(X) = E(Y)$ isn't relevant. For the other direction, have you tried to show that when $\Sigma$ is block diagonal the density factors?

Comment: You could compute the density $f_{(X,Y)}$ of $(X,Y)$ and show that it is equal to $f_X \cdot f_Y$...